# Why do I get an error type with an argument that is used twice for the same purpose

Tags: dictionary, types, ocaml

First of all, I have these types :

```
type position = float * float

type node = position

type path = position list
```

Here are the two pieces of code causing the error :

```
let build_path map source target =
  let rec build_aux acc map source x initial_target =
    if (((DistMap.find_opt x map) = None) || x = source) then acc@[initial_target]
    else build_aux ((DistMap.find x map)::acc) map source (DistMap.find x map) initial_target
  in build_aux [] map source target target

let shortest_path graph source target : path =
  build_path (snd (dijkstra graph source target)) source target
```

`path` has type `position list` for clarity.

Here's the error :

```
361 |   build_path (snd (dijkstra graph source target)) source target
                                                               ^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type position list
       but an expression was expected of type position = float * float
```

I just don't get it. I've tried the build_path function in Utop, by having a Map filled like this :

```
DistMap.bindings prevMap;;
- : (node * (float * float)) list =
[((1., 1.), (7., 7.)); ((2., 2.), (1., 1.)); ((3., 3.), (2., 2.));
 ((4., 4.), (3., 3.)); ((5., 5.), (4., 4.))]
```

```
let l = build_list prevMap (1.,1.) (5.,5.);;
val l : node list = [(1., 1.); (2., 2.); (3., 3.); (4., 4.); (5., 5.)]
```

`shortest_path` has to, with 100% certainty, receive `target` with type `node`. The thing is, no error is raised when target is used as an argument for the `dijsktra` function, which requires a `graph` and two nodes `source` and `target`.

So I'm really confused why target suddenly has the wrong type for `build_path` and not `dijkstra`.

Anyway to resolve this issue?

Comment: what is the meaning of `:` in `let shortest_path graph source target : path` ?

Comment: @PierreG. It's only been a couple months of coding in OCaml, but apparently it's for specifying the return value, in this case a ```position list```, because ```path``` has type ```position list```. That's if I'm not mistaken of course. Plus I edited my post, I forgot to mention the ```path``` type I have.

Comment: I do not think you have to specify the type of the result - the compiler does it for you in general. What is the signature of `build_path` ?

Comment: In Utop, ```build_path``` has type ```val build_path : node DistMap.t -> node -> node -> node list = <fun>```. I tried removing ```: path```, I have the same error output. ```target``` still has ```position list``` somehow ...

Comment: So the error occurs when compiling `shortest_path` ?

Comment: @PierreG. Yes !

Comment: sounds weird to me (since the type of `target` is driven by `build_path` signature). did you try using another name than target ? (foo for instance) ; there might be target already typed somewhere in you code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205350/discussion-between-tiertwo-and-pierre-g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Pierre G., we determined that `target` type was constrained to a `position list` by the `dijkstra` function because I was comparing a list in `dijkstra` with target, once the mistake was fixed and `target` was compared with another `node` in `dijkstra`, the issue was solved.